# Growth function of locally compact groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory, topological-groups

Every locally compact second countable group $G$ has a regular left-invariant measure $h$, the Haar measure. On the other hand the Birkhoff–Kakutani Theorem asserts that such groups also admit a compatible left-invariant metric $d$. Let us denote by $B(id_G,r)$ the $d$-open ball around the identity of radius $r$.

I'm interested in the relations between $h$ and $d$. More precisely I'm curious about the function $$Gr_d:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R,\quad r\mapsto h(B(id_G,r)).$$

Clearly this function is monotone increasing right-continuous but in general (?) not continuous. The function $Gr_d$ is not continuous at $r\in\mathbb R$ if and only if the boundary of the $r$-ball has positive measure. However since it is monotone there are only countably many point of discontinuity.

My first question is: given a l.c.s.c. group $G$ is there a left-invariant metric $d$ such that $Gr_d$ is continuous?

In most of the groups I know, there exists a canonical metric for which the growth $Gr_d$ is continuous. But in general I have no idea how to construct such a metric.

The second question is about how bad things can go: does anyone have an example of a l.c.s.c. group G and a compatible left-invariant metric $d$ for which $Gr_d$ is not continuous? Can $\mathbb R^2$ have such metrics? Given an at most countable subset $C\subset \mathbb R$ can I find a metric on $\mathbb R^2$ (or your favorite l.c.s.c. group) for which the set of discontinuity points of $Gr_d$ is exactly $C$?

**Edit:** Here it is what I meant but didn't write (thanks for the comments!):

- The group $G$ is non-discrete
- The metric $d$ is proper

And this third point would make me even happier

- The closure of any open ball is the closed ball of the same radius

Comment: Do you want to assume $G$ is connected?  Otherwise any discrete group is a counterexample...

Comment: $Gr_d$ is continuous at every $r<0$, and is continuous at zero iff $G$ is non-discrete.

Comment: There's a largest left-invariant metric on $\mathbf{R}$ such that $d(x,0)\le x$ for all $x\ge 0$ and $d(x,0)\le 1$ for all $x\in [1,2]$. This metric is compatible and indeed $d(x,0)=\min(x,1)$ for all $x\in [0,2]$. The 1-sphere equals all $\pm[1,2]$ and has positive measure, so we have discontinuity then.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, sorry, I want to assume that $G$ is not discrete.

Comment: @YCor Can you please explain to me why (and if) you can get a proper metric with your construction?

Comment: If $G$ is the multiplicative group of the $p$-adic numbers, then the metric takes values in the cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb Q^\times$ generated by $p$.  It satisfies your condition on ball closures.  I don't remember the definition of a proper metric, so I'm not sure if it qualifies.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, you are right, this is a good example. Probably any totally disconnect group carry a metric with similar properties

Comment: @LSpice The multiplicative group of nonzero $p$-adics is direct product of a compact group $K$ by $\mathbf{Z}$. So it's somewhat a decorated version of a discrete group. In addition, you should specify the metric, because the standard $p$-adic norm is not left-invariant by multiplication.

Comment: For the metric on $\mathbf{R}$ of my previous comment: define $L(x)=n+x$ for $n\ge 0$, $x\in [2n,2n+1]$ and $L(x)=n+1$ for $x\in [2n+1,2n+2]$. This is well-defined and subadditive. So the distance $N(x,y)=L(|x-y|)$ is the proper left-invariant distance I referred to.

Comment: The edited question looks like "I'd like a locally compact, non-discrete group, with a proper left-invariant metric". This is a trivial question...

Comment: Thanks to @YCor for pointing out two problems with [my example](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/262377/growth-function-of-locally-compact-groups/262408#comment647455_262377):  the metric I had in mind isn't left-invariant (which can be fixed by working with the additive rather than the multiplicative group), and closures of open balls need not be closed balls of the same radius (which cannot be so fixed).  Where should I turn in my p-adic analyst's badge?

Answer (score 1):

Since Wikipedia tells me that a proper metric space is one in which every closed ball is compact, I think that a modification of my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262377/growth-function-of-locally-compact-groups#comment647455_262377) will work:  namely, the additive group of a $p$-adic field (i.e., complete, non-Archimedean, non-trivially discretely valued field with finite residue field), with its usual metric.  (Maybe it violates some spirit of the question, though.  For example, it is essentially maximally non-Euclidean; an $(n + 1)$-point subset of $\mathbb Q_p$ embeds isometrically in $\mathbb R^n$, but in no smaller Euclidean space.)

EDIT:  I originally suggested the multiplicative group, but [@YCor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262377/growth-function-of-locally-compact-groups#comment647483_262408) pointed out that doesn't work.

Comment: You need to specify the metric on the multiplicative group.

Comment: And clearly $\mathbf{Q}_p^*$ admits no proper compatible left-invariant ultrametric.

Comment: @YCor, oh, right, I ignored the crucial 'left-invariant' part.  I guess the additive group (with its usual metric) should still work, though.

Comment: But in the additive group, the open 1-ball is closed, i.e. equal to its closure, but not equal to the "closed 1-ball".

Comment: I actually don't know which question you claim to answer.

Comment: @YCor, ah, of course [that](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/262377/growth-function-of-locally-compact-groups/262408#comment647489_262408)'s true; how embarrassing.  I think I answered the original question (can the growth function be discontinuous?) positively, and satisfied 'propriety' and non-discreteness, but, as you point out, did not satisfy the additional condition that the closure of an open ball is the corresponding closed ball (although I incorrectly [said](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/262377/growth-function-of-locally-compact-groups/262408#comment647455_262377) that I did).